# DateTime#strptime returning invalid date error

Tags: ruby, string, datetime, strptime

I have a string which is scraped from [Daunt Books](https://www.dauntbooks.co.uk/events/):

```
"Monday 2 December 6.30pm"
```

but I can't seem to convert it to a DateTime with `DateTime#strptime`. The date part seems to work:

```
(byebug) DateTime.strptime(str,"%A %d %B")
#<DateTime: 2019-12-02T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458820j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

but the time returns an error:

```
(byebug) DateTime.strptime(str,"%A %d %B %l.%M%P")
*** ArgumentError Exception: invalid date

nil
```

I know this is the correct `#strptime` code because it works on the string if it is not scraped from the web page. I can't work out what I need to do to make the string valid for `#strptime` to work.

EDIT:

Unfortunately the website I was scraping from was redesigned the day after the OP and the scraping code is now defunkt.

Comment: Please test again. If you still get the exception what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: _"I know this is the correct #strptime code because it works on the string if it is not scraped from the web page"_ – so apparently the bug's cause is outside of what you have posted here. Please show your scraping code or better yet, a [mcve]. And there seems to be some preprocessing as well: _"Monday 2 December 6.30pm"_ (your string) vs. _"Monday 2**nd** December **at** 6.30pm"_ (date on website, emphasis mine)

Comment: please see the edited OP -- the website referred to in the OP has changed so the post is now out of date. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I can't duplicate the problem:

```
require 'date'

str = "Monday 2 December 6.30pm"
DateTime.strptime(str,"%A %d %B %l.%M%P") 
# => #<DateTime: 2019-12-02T18:30:00+00:00 ((2458820j,66600s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

And this works for me:

```
require 'date'

foo = "Monday 2 December 6.30pm"

bar = DateTime.strptime(foo, '%a %d %B %l.%M%p')
bar.to_s
# => "2019-12-02T18:30:00+00:00"
```

and:

```
DateTime.strptime(foo, '%a %d %B %l.%M%p').strftime('%A %e %B %l:%M%p') 
# => "Monday  2 December  6:30PM"
```